# Albums are not visible in Ubuntu One Music

Tags: music, mp3, id3

I have a problem with my MP3 files, wich i uploaded to my Ubuntu One Cloud account.
Cause i´m using Ubuntu One Music too, i uploaded several of my MP3 files in a folder.

I recognized, that in my One Music account, those files which do not have any ID3 tag are visible as unknown artist-unknown title-unknown album.
So i dowloaded EasyTag on my Ubuntu Desktop and edited all of them to correct ID3 tags.

On the first album that i have uploaded, this went well and the album is correctly recognized and visible (even with its playlist numbers)... well its not a correct album indeed. I created myself a "Best-Of" album from this artist and uploadet the MP3 files which i want to have on this "album". But it went well, so i thought that this would be the way to do this stuff.

I have done the same on a few other artists and now the problems have begun.

The files are correctly stored in my cloud account but are not visible in my One Music account.
I did not see the album and also not the files. Only on the "artists" region, i will see the files and can stream them.
The other weird problem is, that some albums are recognized correctly by their name and if i click on on of those, i also see only a few MP3 files which are streamable and not all of them.
For example i made a Best-Of Album of Feeder and uploadet 12 MP3 Files ... the album is visible as "Feeder - Best Of" and then there are only 3 Songs available to stream.

Does anyone of you have an idea, what its going wrong on my One Music account?
The files are standard MP3 files without any DRM stuff.

And sorry if my english is not the best .. cause i am austrian, my native language is german :)

Comment: No ideas? :( ... What a pitty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... "Album Artist" do the trick.
Edit all files to "Various Artists" and all works great :)